# Use real server instead of docker-machine for OSX

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I have a linux on cloud with a installed docker service on it. How can I use my VS on cloud instead of `docker-machine` on my OSX? it means instead of install VirtualBox and create a VM on it by `docker-machine`, I use my server on cloud as docker server.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Are you saying you want to take your dockerized service and run it on a cloud server somewhere?  What cloud platform are you talking about?  Maybe I am misunderstanding...

Comment: @aTotalStranger sorry I mean VS. I have a VS on digitaloceans and I want use it instead making VM on my laptop (its mac and i should use boot2docker). It means when I run `docker start ...` on laptop it starts mentioned image on my VS

Answer (score 1):

You might get a solution from docker-machine's [generic driver](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/generic/). Just start the virtual server in cloud, set up proper SSH keys and get started :) It should work just the same as with a VM within VirtualBox.

I'm not sure how to get VS auto-started if it is shut down though. Via a could-vendor specific command line program?

**Edit**: I should have read the docs better, the first [cloud example](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started-cloud/) actually shows the usage of digital ocean driver. If it is already running then just use the generic driver.

Comment: He already has docker up and running on his remote box. The question is about accessing it from his local machine.

Comment: If it is already running then the generic driver is all he needs.

Answer (score 1):

To access a remote Docker daemon simply pass the `-H` flag to your docker commands:

```
docker -H=tcp://192.168.0.100:2375 images
```

You need to ensure that the remote Docker daemon is listening on the appropriate network interface. **Be aware though that doing this on an external server is highly insecure**, anyone that can reach the port has effectively root access on the server. At the very least read [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/https/) article on securing the Docker daemon.

Personally I would only recommend using a `port binding via ssh tunnel` to access the remote Docker daemon.